# python - Write in different files created

Tags: python, loops, text

I would like to create, let's say, 100 folders, and in each folder create a txt file. And I would like to write different things in each text file, because of some conditions. I can create the folders, and create the file in each folder. But by using with **open('...') as f :**, I am not able to write different things in each text file.

Here is the code to create the folders and the files. It works perfectly.

```
def createAndFillFolders():

    for i in range(100):
        dir_name = (('/home/pi/Project/folder_%s') % (i))
        if os.path.exists(dir_name): # if the folder already exists
            shutil.rmtree(dir_name) # then overwrite
        os.makedirs(dir_name)
        open(os.path.join(dir_name, "file_%s" % (i + 1)), "w")
```

But if now I want to write different things in each file, I can't find a way to do this properly.
I tried using os.path.join with open but it doesn't work when I use "open with(...) :

```
    with open(os.path.join(dire_name,'/file_%s.txt' % (i + 1, i + 1), "w") as #("file_%i.txt" % (i + 1)):
        ("file_%i.txt" % (i + 1)).write("%i" %(i + 1))
```

I know this last part of code is completly false but it could help to understand what I would like to have.

So each folder_i has a file_i.txt file with "i" written inside.

Thanks for helping !!

Comment: so you're able to create all files and folder right? you just need assistance with writin some stuff to file.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to reinvent a map or list of files with the "how do I dynamically name variables" antipattern. Why do you need the handles to each file to be called different things?

Comment: Does `with open(.....) as f: \n\t f.write("%i" %(i+1))` not work?

Comment: @harshil9968 yes need to write different things in each file

Comment: @JETM it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def writeToFiles():

    for i in range(100):
        dir_name = (('/home/pi/Project/folder_%s') % (i))
        f = open(os.path.join(dir_name, "file_%s" % (i + 1)), "w")
        f.write(str(i))
        f.close()
```

This is one to do it I will prefer that you do that while creating your files and folder only for that you will do something like this:

```
def createAndFillFolders():

    for i in range(100):
        dir_name = (('/home/pi/Project/folder_%s') % (i))
        if os.path.exists(dir_name): # if the folder already exists
            shutil.rmtree(dir_name) # then overwrite
        os.makedirs(dir_name)
        f = open(os.path.join(dir_name, "file_%s" % (i + 1)), "w")
        f.write(str(i))
        f.close()
```

Let me know if you face any error, or is stuck somewhere.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, same as @JETM.
Thanks a lot for that